# Remove speaker connector for 2002 Dodge Caravan

Tags: connector, speakers

I can't figure out how to remove the front driver's side speaker in my 2002 Dodge Caravan. I would have thought you just pull the red tab back and pull it off but it won't budge. Is there some trick to it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It looks as though the back (top of the picture) of the red connector has a bar which must be pushed down (away from the picture) and under the black portion, then slid back (away from the speaker or up in the picture)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These connectors often have a tab that "clicks" into place and prevents them from working loose. There are various designs, but usually there is some part that you press down or prize up to release them.

The easiest way to see how they work is to take note of what happens when you plug them together, but that isn't very helpful advice when your first task is to unplug one!

As soon as the connector starts to "unplug" you can let go of the locking tab.

For the Dodge van, this video shows how to release the connector, at about 3 minutes from the start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkqdcfCyaew

Comment: The video is a bit unclear but what you have to do is after pulling back the red part you hold down on the black tab and pull the connector off.